# Transform Timestamp Without Time Zone to a simple date in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, date, timestamp

Suppose I have a column that has the datatype `Timestamp without Time Zone` and looks like this:

```
Sun Jan 01 1933 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)
```

I want to change it to a simple date like this `01/01/1933`.
I have tried the following, but there is no change in the output:

```
SELECT timestamp_date::date as new_date,
       DATE(timestamp_date) as also_date
FROM my_schema.my_table;
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Your date is already a date, in ISO format. If you want to transform this to some different format, text, you can you the function to_char() and the parameters you need. Personally I would never do this in the database, but always in the presentation layer of my application

Comment: Can you fiddle it? Also remember you can cast as ::timestamp without time zone

Comment: @FrankHeikens, no that is not a date format it is datetime format.  Nor is it the ISO format. A ISO date format would be `1993-01-1` See here [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Dates) for more information.

Comment: What version of Postgres? What client are you using to run the query? Because this `Sun Jan 01 1933 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)` is not valid in Postgres: `select 'Sun Jan 01 1933 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)'::timestamp; ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type timestamp: "Sun Jan 01 1933 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)"`

Comment: @AdrianKlaver: missed that completely! Just saw the casting to a date… Need some coffee, too early in the morning to start without

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the function [to_char](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html#FUNCTIONS-FORMATTING-DATETIME-TABLE)

`to_char(timestamp_date, 'DD/MM/YYYY');`

Or you can play with `DATESTYLE` configuration parameters, but use to_char always as possible, to avoid the change of configuration